# Change Background Color of datagrid cell based on more than one condition in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Hi I'm very new to Adobe Flex, apologize if my question sounds stupid. Anyhow here it is.
I am trying simple datagrid which checks basically 2 conditions
1) If the Artist is 01 and Album is 'Album 01' set Background to corresponding cell in Column 'Year'.

With my below code 'set Style' to Background Color as property is not working but changing the font color is working and secondly i am not sure how to write the code to get the above nested conditions working? If anybody could help me in this aspect i would be really be grateful.
Thank you! in Advance.

Below is the code:
Newdatagrid.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 

           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955"          minHeight="600" >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        [Bindable]
        public static var initDG:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Artist:'01', Album:'Album 01', Year:'2008'},
            {Artist:'01', Album:'Album 02', Year:'2009'},
            {Artist:'03', Album:'Album 03', Year:'2007'},
            {Artist:'03', Album:'Album 04', Year:'2003'},

        ]); 

    ]]>

</fx:Script>


<s:VGroup>
    <s:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="360" dataProvider="{initDG}">   
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="Artist"    headerText="Artist" itemRenderer="CellRenderer"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="Album" headerText="Album" itemRenderer="CellRenderer"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="Year" headerText="Year" itemRenderer="CellRenderer"/>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>       
    </s:DataGrid> 
</s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                    implements="mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
        import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        private var _listData:BaseListData;

        [Bindable]private var isSelected:Boolean = false;

        override public function set data( value:Object ) : void 
        {
            super.data = value;
            lblData.text = data[column.dataField];

            if (data[column.dataField].valueOf() >= 2008){
                //styleName="myStyles.BgColor";
                setStyle('backgroundColor',0xFFFF00);
            }else{
                setStyle('backgroundColor',0x32CD32);
            }

        }

        [Bindable]public function get listData() : BaseListData
        {
            return _listData;
        }
        public function set listData( value:BaseListData ) : void
        {
            _listData = value;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Label id="lblData" top="9" left="7" width="100%" height="100%"    textAlign="center"/>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

My Desired Output: Condition: If Artist=01 and Year >= 2008 then cell Background of Year change to Red

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748213/setting-background-color-for-datagrid-row-in-adobe-flex refer this link.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, however I'm unable to get the entire code and source code link says the site as expired.

Answer (score 7):

The class GridItemRenderer has no such style backgroundColor.
So it has no effect setting it.

What you can do is to add a Rect to the ItemRenderer and set its color property according to your condition.

an example would be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {


                if(this.data) {

                    if(this.data.Year >= 2008 && this.data.Artist == '01' && column.dataField == 'Year') 
                        bgColor.color = 0xFF0000;
                    else
                        bgColor.color = 0xFFFFFF;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Rect top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor id="bgColor" color="0xFFFFFF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Label id="labelDisplay" top="9" left="7"/>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Thanks michPooh for your prompt response. Your code highlights the entire row, instead i would require it to higlight only those cells which match the condition in column 'Year'.My Desired Output: Condition: For e.g If Artist=01 and Year >= 2008 then the corresponding cell Background of Year change to Red, in this example   it will be 2008 only.

Comment: just change the condition to e.g. if(this.data.Year >= 2008 && this.data.Artist == '01' && column.dataField == 'Year')
      bgColor.color = 0xFF0000;
     else
      bgColor.color = 0xFFFFFF;

Comment: Wow! Man thanks a lot! I have been suffering a lot because of this issue! You made my day. Thanks Again!

Comment: The item renderer overrides the Label function defined in spark Datagrid column, which calls function for currency format, so now the column does not show the Currency or number format. Could you provide a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: give your Label object in the itemRenderer the id="labelDisplay" and delete the code `lblData.text = data[column.dataField];`. this should do the trick - i will update the code above

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 

               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955"          minHeight="600" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            [Bindable]
            public static var initDG:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {Artist:'01', Album:'Album 01', Year:'2008'},
                {Artist:'01', Album:'Album 02', Year:'2009'},
                {Artist:'03', Album:'Album 03', Year:'2007'},
                {Artist:'03', Album:'Album 04', Year:'2003'},

            ]); 

        ]]>

    </fx:Script>


    <s:VGroup>
        <s:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="360" dataProvider="{initDG}">   
            <s:columns>
                <s:ArrayList>
                    <s:GridColumn dataField="Artist"    headerText="Artist"/>
                    <s:GridColumn dataField="Album" headerText="Album"/>
                    <s:GridColumn dataField="Year" headerText="Year" itemRenderer="CellRenderer"/>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:columns>       
        </s:DataGrid> 
    </s:VGroup>
</s:WindowedApplication>

----------------------------CellRenderer.mxml------------------------

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
                lblData.text = data[column.dataField]
                if(this.data) {
                    lblData.text = data[column.dataField];

                    if(this.data.Year >= 2008&&this.data.Artist==01)
                        bgColor.color = 0xFF0000;
                    else
                        bgColor.color = 0xFFFFFF;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Rect top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor id="bgColor" color="0xFFFFFF"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Label id="lblData" top="9" left="7" width="100%" height="100%" textAlign="center"/>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Comment: Thank you! Since i was using the spark component for datagrid, i have used override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void which stopped my data from becoming incorrect when i scroll the datagrid.

Comment: The item renderer overrides the Label function defined in spark Datagrid column, which calls function for currency format, so now the column does not show the Currency or number format. Could you provide a solution for this? Thanks in advance.