# Select Specific Row and change color of row c#

Tags: c#, datagrid

i am seeking a bit of help with a piece of code, i am trying to select one single row out of about 20 and make this row a different color from the rest, which will would be the best way to go about this, first of all i created a if statement `if (name equals "TOTAL")` make row a different color, i am unsure of how to do this select and change the color of this row, The row needs to be selected within a flex grid

```
if (benchName.Equals("TOTAL"))
   {
      for (int AB = 0; AB < 24; i++)
      {
       this.grid2.Cell(4, AB).BackColor = Color.Red;
       }                             
    }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748213/setting-background-color-for-datagrid-row-in-adobe-flex

Answer (score 0):

The if (benchName.Equals("TOTAL")) statement shoud be inside the for statement,
or some other if statement where you verify the right cell to change the colour.