# Change BackgroundColor of particular row dynamic in DataGrid in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, actionscript, flex4.6

I am trying to change Mx `DataGridColumn` background color depend on it's data dynamically but didn't get/found any solution for that.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="orderDG" dataProvider="{ordersList}" >
        <mx:columns>                    
            <mx:DataGridColumn width="30" headerText="Number" dataField="no" />

            <mx:DataGridColumn width="250" headerText="fname" dataField="fname">

            <mx:DataGridColumn width="250" headerText="lname" dataField="lname">

         </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Now, suppose i want to make row **color green** if `fname=abc` and **color red** if `fname=xyz`.

How i can change background and text color of only that row.

**Edit:**

I will try creating custom renderer like following way.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            setStyle("color", MATCH_COLOR );

        }
```

But it will change color of only one cell not whole row.

Comment: create custom renderer.

Comment: custom renderer. How?

Comment: @BotMaster please read my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post :

[Setting background color for datagrid row in Adobe Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748213/setting-background-color-for-datagrid-row-in-adobe-flex)

Does it answer your question?

Comment: There is change text color of particular cell. I want change color(background) of whole row dynamically.

Comment: No, its for changing the background color of the entire row. Read the post. The post does say "Setting background color for datagrid row in Adobe Flex". Isn't that what you need?

Comment: In there given link. 2 is not working. 1 will suggest AndvancDatagrid, another one given solution for spark datagrid and one gives solution but just change only particular cell color.